# Is it possible to access server control from page method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, pagemethods, servercontrols

I would like to update a Gridviews datasource using JQuery and page methods, but I'm not sure how to access the Gridview control I created on the page. I know I can't access the instance of it, but I want to access the id so just rebind it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something specific you are doing with this Gridview? If not, I would also suggest (as Niels suggests) to use an ajax call (use jQuery) and instead of a Gridview try a Table. [Check this nice HTML Gridview out](http://www.devtechie.com/post/2011/05/13/JSON-GridViewTable-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-Web-Service.aspx). It uses jQuery, JSON, WebService.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update you have to build a webmethod. Seet his page for more information: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

If you got a Webmethod, you can access that function by calling something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.aspx/webmethodname",
    success : function(data){}
})
```

But then you have to build your Gridview through code.

Or use default Ajax from asp.net: http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-AJAX-GridView-Loading.aspx